# the body message of email has %20 instead of spaces

Tags: javascript, email

The link to the ide I code in from `sololearn.com` is https://code.sololearn.com/Wg70wiK3e0h3/#html but there I can never actually send the email, so then I use the notepad and the body message that is sent is filled by %20 as if it was a link. The "code" below is the function in which I build the body message and send the email. If you go to my full code in `sololearn` it is in line `2000ish` and its called in line `3000ish`. By the way the rest of the code is working perfectly fine.

This function has more to it but it's too big to put it here but basically I add the data to the message variable, just like the gender one but multiple times with multiple variables, but all with the same syntax. I tried using `decodeURI` but then it does not work once it's a link. Is there another way to send the email, a way in which the body message isn't all screwed up?

```
function sendEmail() {

        message = "Hi this is just a way for you to have all the main data summed up saved in your email inbox. \n \n";

        message += "Gender: ";

        message += genderreturn;

        message += " \n";

        url = "mailto:" + emailaddrreturn + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;

        location.href = url; //(might want to use window.location or something else here)
}
```

Comment: If you mean when you open it in your email client it shows all the spaces as %20's, that's weird. I just tried it for myself and it's working (obviously I used different variables).

Comment: Yeah, I mean when you have to send the email, the body message is all screwed up because of those %20. Maybe its because everything is written in a link and the link has to be encoded. But if it did work for you, what did you do to that last line?